# Can't install Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Trying to install Devise and I get the following message "Could not find generator devise:install."

```
leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$ bundle install
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.11
Using json 1.8.1
Using minitest 5.4.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 1.2.1
Using activesupport 4.1.4
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using actionview 4.1.4
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.1.4
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.1.4
Using activemodel 4.1.4
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using activerecord 4.1.4
Using execjs 2.2.1
Using autoprefixer-rails 2.1.1.20140710
Using bcrypt 3.1.7
Using sass 3.2.19
Using bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.1.4
Using bootswatch-rails 3.2.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.7.1
Using coffee-script 2.3.0
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using data-confirm-modal 1.0.1 from git://github.com/ifad/data-confirm-modal.git (at master)
Using declarative_authorization 0.5.7
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using warden 1.2.3
Using devise 3.2.4
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using jbuilder 2.1.3
Using jquery-rails 3.1.1
Using bundler 1.6.4
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.11.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.1.3
Using rails 4.1.4
Using rdoc 4.1.1
Using sass-rails 4.0.3
Using sdoc 0.4.0
Using spring 1.1.3
Using sqlite3 1.3.9
Using turbolinks 2.2.2
Using uglifier 2.5.3
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$ rails generate devise:install
Could not find generator devise:install.
leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$
```

My Gemfile is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0.0'
gem 'bootswatch-rails', '~> 3.2.0'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'

# Use data-confirm-modal to create custom alert modal popups
gem 'data-confirm-modal', github: 'ifad/data-confirm-modal'

# Use devise for user authentication
gem 'devise'
# Use declarative_authorization for user authorisation
gem 'declarative_authorization'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Rails version is:

```
leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$ rails -v
Rails 4.1.4
leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$
```

OS version is:

```
leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$
```

Any ideas as to why the Devise gem won't install after correctly adding it to the Gemfile and running the bundle install?

I did have the server running at one point (rails server) and saw an article stating that attempting to install Devise whilst the server is up could cause strange issues.

I've since tried again with the server down but no difference.  I'm sure this is probably happening due to something really simple that I overlooked in the setup, just not sure where else to look.

Any advise or suggestions on where to look next would be great, thanks.

I've done testing using the command below but still received the same error:

```
leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$ bundle exec rails g devise:install
Could not find generator devise:install.
```

The list of installed generators are below and Devise is not listed, how do I get it listed?

```
leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$ rails generate
Usage: rails generate GENERATOR [args] [options]

General options:
  -h, [--help]     # Print generator's options and usage
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output

Please choose a generator below.

Rails:
  assets
  controller
  generator
  helper
  integration_test
  jbuilder
  mailer
  migration
  model
  resource
  scaffold
  scaffold_controller
  task

Coffee:
  coffee:assets

Jquery:
  jquery:install

Js:
  js:assets

TestUnit:
  test_unit:generator
  test_unit:plugin

leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$
```

Comment: If you type `rails generate` do you see devise options anywhere?

Comment: Are you using RVM or any other version manager. You could be installing the Devise gem on a different gemset than the one you're expecting.

Comment: No, running rails generate does not list devise

Comment: I'm using rbenv for version control/management.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I'm still not 100% sure why this worked or what caused the issue in the first place but after running the following commands:

```
leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$ gem uninstall devise
Successfully uninstalled devise-3.2.4
leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$ gem uninstall warden
Successfully uninstalled warden-1.2.3
leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
[... text removed ...]
Installing warden 1.2.3
Installing devise 3.2.4
[... text removed ...]
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$ rails generate devise:install
      create  config/initializers/devise.rb
      create  config/locales/devise.en.yml
```

Woo Hoo!!! problem solved.  Great way to waste a couple of days :-(

Answer (score 11):

same problem today, I removed the 'spring' out from the Gemfile and it did the trick.
or you can turn off your spring first and run rails generate devise:install

Comment: and after removed the 'spring' and run rails generate devise:install should I add it back? Actually removing the 'spring' did not works to me

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was:

```
$ sudo -s
$ bundle exec rails generate devise:install
```

Without sudo or running the "initializer" `/bin/bash --login` didn't work. The other solution could be to remove the Gemfile.lock and run `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work on my machine under RVM, but that's with a fresh gemset. If you're using version of Ruby (or an RVM gemset) shared with other Rails installs, you could be having problems there.

As you're using Bundler you should probably use:

```
bundle exec rails g devise:install
```

as a general precaution, to ensure you're using the bundle's gems.

Comment: Hi @AFaderDarkly, I've tried this command and have updated my original post above with results.

Comment: I see from other comments that you're using rbenv. I'm an rvm user and I unfortunately don't have any rbenv experience. However, one thing to look at may be the location of the 'rails' command you're using and the location of the ruby gems for the ruby version you're using. If they don't match up, the rails command from another ruby version may be overriding the one you want. Another thing to check (looking at the rbenv docs) is to make sure ~/.rbenv/shims is at the start of your path. (Look in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile if  you're on Linux or OSX with bash shell.)

Comment: Thanks Fader, checked the following and both paths match and I changed my PATH so that the shims path is at the start but still no joy :-(

leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$ rbenv --version
rbenv 0.4.0-98-g13a474c
leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$ which rails
/home/leigh/.rbenv/shims/rails
leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$ which ruby
/home/leigh/.rbenv/shims/ruby

Comment: leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$ echo $PATH
/home/leigh/.rbenv/shims:/home/leigh/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/leigh/.rbenv/bin:/home/leigh/.rbenv/shims:/home/leigh/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/leigh/.rbenv/bin:/home/leigh/.rbenv/shims:/home/leigh/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/leigh/.rbenv/shims:/home/leigh/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
leigh@leigh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/dev01$

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. :(

Have you tried using the same ruby version with a new install of Rails and a Gemfile with **only** devise installed? If that works (as it did for me) then try adding your other gem dependencies until it breaks.

Comment: I did gem uninstall devise then ran that command. worked for me! thnk you :)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding the following line to my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'devise'
```

After adding that line, I executed `bundle install`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. I tried uninstalling `devise` and `warden` but no luck. Finally I deleted the `Gemfile.lock` and ran `bundle install` again and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This will sound ridiculous but open a new terminal window and try again. That's what it ended up being for me.  If that still doesn't work, try:

`DISABLE_SPRING=1 bundle exec rails g devise:install`

Answer (score 0):

I  had the same problem today in vscode terminal, try remove the gemfile.lock and if doesn't work, repeate the below process.

You can remove de gemfile and after try bundle install on a new terminal.

I'm think this is a permission problem on vscode.

In first step you can remove the line of devise on gemfile and add again manually -> gemfile 'devise'

Steps:

- 1.0 try on your terminal.
- 1.1 remove gemfile.lock.
- 1.2 run bundle install.
- 1.3 run rails g devise:install.

If doesn't work

- 2.0 Quit the terminal e open a new.
- 2.1 try run the same steps on 1.1 to 1.3

Solved to me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using:

```
gem 'rack-cors', :require 'rack-cors'
```

Then I got the same error but none of the solutions here solved it.

I had to replace it just to be like this:

```
gem 'rack-cors'
```

then run

> $ bundle install

> $ rails generate devise:install

Answer (score 0):

I close my terminal and open a new one.
Then rails generate devise:install

It works this time. It is so weired!

Answer (score -1):

Restarting the console will fix this issue.